# Updating continuously listview with data from an ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I need to bind a list an observablecollection to the listview. This listview must be updated each time when data changes in the observablecollection.
For now I can only  bind one element of the observablecollection to the listview at the same time, whenever the second one is bound, it will cover the last one.
My purpose is to bind all the data which are created by calling LoadAlarms() in  to the listview .

[These are my XAML codes:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6E9f.png)

[my Alarms class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8RyO.png)

[My codes in viewmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIk33.png)

[the fist time LoadAlarms are called, I have the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQb38.png)

[The second time LoadAlarms are called,I have the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEmOH.png)

I would like to display these both results to the listview but I can only see the last update.

Comment: Don't use images of the code. Type your code in the question. You must make it easier for people to use your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call LoadAlarm() you overwrite your observable collection with a new one.

Call `AlarmList = new ObservableCollection<Alarms>()` only once for example in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your class Alarms must be inherited from NotificationObject and its properties must do RaisePropertyChanged whenever they change.
2. ObservableCollection should be allocated once and then only use add, remove etc.
3. Why do you have a ListView that contains a grid that contains a grid that contains another ListView? What are you trying to do if I may ask.

Hope this helps..